# how can I do email verification for an android app using node js?

Tags: java, node.js, mongodb, android-studio

I'm building a sign up page for an android studio application, and I've been searching for a way to do email verification using node js and mongodb, but couldn't find anything useful till now, can any one help?

Comment: [Send an email](https://davidcel.is/posts/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/). If it's valid, it will be received.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly use the NPM Package **(two-step-auth)**

Use this package in your server index.js and create a route for it, and directly pass in the variables and you can do the rest,

In your app get the data from the form and pass it to your server and then to the package and it will return you an OTP to work with,

[Kindly check the full procedures with example here](https://github.com/saran-surya/two-step-auth)

Happy Coding :)

### Usage

```js
const {Auth} = require('two-step-auth');

async function login(emailId){
    const res = await Auth(emailId);
    // You can follw the above approach, But we recommend you to follow the one below, as the mails will be treated as important
    const res = await Auth(emailId, "Company Name");
    console.log(res);
    console.log(res.mail);
    console.log(res.OTP);
    console.log(res.success);
}

const app = express();
app.get('./auth/mailId/CompanyName', async(req, res)=>{
    const {emailId} = req.params;
    const data  = login(emailId);
})
```

### Output

[image]
This will help you a lot taking care of the process of verification under the HOOD :)